# Getting error Validation Failed: 1: No aggregation found for path [data] in elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

While trying aggregataion in elasticsearch getting error  Validation Failed: 1: No aggregation found for path [data]
how to access data.value inside ply?

```
get colors/_search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"types": {
"terms": {"field": "colortype.keyword"},
"aggs": {
"color": {"terms": { "field": "color.keyword" },
"aggs": {"price": {"sum": {"script": "doc['price'].value * 2"}}}
},
"data": {"avg_bucket": {"buckets_path": "color>price"}},
"ply": { "terms": {"field": "color.keyword"},
"aggs": { "price": {"sum": { "script": "doc['price'].value * 2" }},
"priceSubAvg": {
"bucket_script": {
"buckets_path": {
"my_var1": "price",
"my_var2": "data"
},
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"source": "params.my_var1-params.my_var2",
"params": {"avgPrice": 2}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please check elastic aggregation guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html.
You need to define your query based on guidline of ES.